# MATLAB: Permute and reshape a N x 4 array into a 2 x 2 x N array

Tags: arrays, matlab, reshape, transpose

I have a question that seems like it should have a simple answer that can avoid for loops.

Suppose I have an *N* x 4 array defined in MATLAB:

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4];
```

In this example, *N* = 6, but it is arbitrary. I want to re-arrange **A** into a new array, **B**, which is 2 x 2 x *N* array of the form:

```
B(:,:,1) = [1 2; 3 4];
B(:,:,2) = [1 2; 3 4];

...

B(:,:,N) = [1 2; 3 4];
```

This seems like a simple problem and I tried a variety of things such as:

```
B = reshape(A',2,2,N);
```

However, this results in

```
B(:,:,1) = [1 3; 2 4];
B(:,:,2) = [1 3; 2 4];

...

B(:,:,N) = [1 3; 2 4];
```

I feel like there must be a simple way of doing this in one line using some combination of "reshape", "permute" and/or "transpose" that I am missing. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only missing a final [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html). This is needed because Matlab is column-major, so it fills the new array down, then across:

```
B = permute(reshape(A.', 2,2,N), [2 1 3]);
```